# Specifying an alternate shell with rsync

Tags: ssh, shell, rsync, fish

I'm using rsync to sync up files between two computers. On one machine, my default shell is set to fish, which breaks rsync ("protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?").

Is there a way to tell rsync to use /bin/sh instead of the default login shell?

Comment: Remote ssh commands always go through the login shell `-c thecommand`; this cannot be bypassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this in my [rsync man page](http://man.cx/rsync):

> **DIAGNOSTICS**
>
> rsync occasionally produces error messages that may seem a little cryptic. The one that seems  to  cause  the
>          most confusion is "protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?".
>
> This message is usually caused by your startup scripts or remote shell facility producing unwanted garbage on
>          the stream that rsync is using for its transport. The way to diagnose this problem  is  to  run  your  remote
>          shell like this:
>
> ```
> ssh remotehost /bin/true > out.dat
> ```
>
> then  look  at  out.dat. If everything is working correctly then out.dat should be a zero length file. If you
>          are getting the above error from rsync then you will probably find that out.dat contains some text  or  data.
>          Look  at  the contents and try to work out what is producing it. The most common cause is incorrectly configured shell startup scripts (such as .cshrc or .profile) that contain output  statements  for  non-interactive
>          logins.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. I stopped it from outputing things on login and it works fine.